# Difference between ArcPy and ArcGIS API for Python?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-python-api

Could someone explain, from a high level overview, the difference between ArcPy and the new ArcGIS API package in Python?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

arcpy is installed with ArcGIS software and requires a license to use. It is meant to assist in automating complex GIS tasks and extending GIS functionality not available out of the box.  It is still more granular than using ArcObjects however.

The ArcGIS API for python is free to download but is meant to be used with "web GIS".  "ArcGIS API for Python is a Python library for working with maps and geospatial data, powered by web GIS". https://developers.arcgis.com/python/
Seems to require an ArcGIS online or local portal account.